# Cannot ping an ip of router

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, ospf

my issue is:

1. r1 ping r4(em0) will lost the first packet
2. r2 ping r3(em0) will lost the first packet too
3. r3 cannot ping r2(eth0)
4. r4 cannot ping r1(eth0)

---

there are 4 routers, and connected with openvpn(tun).
r1/r2 is ubuntu, and running in AWS EC2.
r3/r4 is pfsense, running in ESXi VM.

r1:

```
eth0: 10.5.1.8/24
tun0: 10.15.0.1 (to r2 tun0)
tun1: 10.15.1.1 (to r3 ovpnc1)
```

r2:

```
eth0: 10.5.2.9/24
tun0: 10.15.0.2 (to r1 tun0)
tun1: 10.15.1.13 (to r4 opvnc1)
```

r3:

```
em0: 192.168.91.1/24 (CARP IP: 192.168.91.3)
em1: 10.15.11.1 (PFSYNC interface, connect to r4 by dedicate vlan)
ovpnc1: 10.15.1.2 (to r1)
```

r4:

```
em0: 192.168.91.2/24 (CARP IP: 192.168.91.3)
em1: 10.15.11.2 (PFSYNC interface, connect to r3 by dedicate vlan)
ovpnc1: 10.15.1.14 (to r2)

r1 -tun - r2
|         |
tun      tun
|         |
r3 -vlan- r4
```

PS: because r1 and r2 are running in AWS,
so r1(10.5.1.0/24) to r2(10.5.2.0/24) is using AWS VPN router(10.5.1.1).

All routers are running OSPF.

details:

from r1 ping:

```
r2(10.5.2.9): success
r2(10.15.0.2): success
r3(192.168.91.1): success
r3(10.15.1.2): success
r4(192.168.91.2): **success, but will lost the first ping packet(always)**
r4(10.15.1.14): success, no packet loss
```

from r2 ping:

```
r1(10.5.1.8): success
r1(10.15.0.1): success
r3(192.168.91.1): **success, the first packet loss too**
r3(10.15.1.2): success, no packet loss
r4(192.168.91.2): success
r4(10.15.1.14): success
```

from r3 ping:

```
r1(10.5.1.8): success
r1(10.15.1.1): success
r2(10.5.2.9): **FAILED, cannot ping**
r2(10.15.0.2): success
r2(10.15.1.13): success
r4(192.168.91.2): success
r4(10.15.11.2): success
```

from r4 ping:

```
r1(10.5.1.8): **FAILED, cannot ping**
r1(10.15.0.1): success
r1(10.15.1.1): success
r2(10.5.2.9): success
r2(10.15.1.13): success
r3(192.168.91.1): success
r3(10.15.11.1): success
```

Comment: What's the actual problem here?

Comment: sorry, @HopelessN00b I edited issue list at top of body.

Comment: I mean what's the actual problem? Why are you pinging stuff?

Comment: @HopelessN00b No actual problem, just i cannot understand why the ping was failed(and lost the first packet).